# Facebook Application Activity Aggregator / Notifier in Newsfeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

Does anyone know what this functionality is called and how it can be implemented?  I do not have any of these apps added to my Facebook account but every so often I get what's shown in the screenshot in my newsfeed.  This is a great way to get click-through's into an application.

[image: Facebook Games]

### UPDATE

A lot of content-delivery sites have this functionality e.g. news sites, and even Pinterest now.  See:

[image: Facebook Pinterest]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Apps and Games** "app" is made by Facebook and has access to functionality not (yet) available to regular 3rd party developers.

The closest thing we can do is aggregation reports: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/

### Update

The Pintrest report looks more like what can be done by us mere mortals.
See for example this report from an app that I made:
[image: Aggregation Report]
<sub>(source: [jocke.syk.se](http://jocke.syk.se/aggreport.jpg))</sub>

Here's what the action settings looks like:
[image: Aggregation Report]

Comment: Joakim, wicked... I'm so stoked to try this out.  Can you point me towards some documentation on how to implement this?  How do you get to the view that you've screenshotted?

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#define). It also shows you how to get there.

Comment: Hi Really nice answer, can we add our custom button along with like and comment.
I want to add read button, when user clicks on this, that will take him to direct on website.

Comment: Hi @Invincible. Clicking on the object title (in this example the movie name) brings you directly to the website for that specific object. In the realtime ticker you get a button labeled "View" that also opens the object-specific website. If you use some of the builtin objects you may get some extra buttons on the aggregation reports as well. Try the "article" object.